With Angular 17, I am creating a shared component to upload an image and it emits a link to the image uploaded
Once I have created the component and used it on the Parent, I need to create two sections on the same Parent component to upload different images.
The problem is if let's say I have 2 sections, section A and section B, the UI is displayed as intended, the problem is when I click section B and upload the image, the image name is being displayed in section A, in short it's overriding whatever was in section A.
This is my fc-image-upload.component.ts:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-fc-image-upload',
    templateUrl: './fc-image-upload.component.html',
    styleUrl: './fc-image-upload.component.scss',
})
export class FcImageUploadComponent {
    selectedFile: any;
    
    @Input({ required: true }) baseUrl: string;
    @Input({ required: true }) headers: HttpHeaders;
    @Output() fcUploadImageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

    private _fcImageUploadService = inject(FcImageUploadService);

    uploadImagetoStorage(event) {
        this.selectedFile = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];

        console.log(this.selectedFile);

        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('uploadedFile', this.selectedFile);

        this._fcImageUploadService
            .uploadFileToStorage(
                data,
                this.selectedFile.type,
                this.headers,
                this.baseUrl
            )
            .subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    console.log(response);

                    this.fcUploadImageEvent.emit(response.mediaLink);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }
}

fc-image-upload.component.html:
<div class="fc-image-container">
    <label for="dropzone-file" class="fc-image-lable"> 
        <div class="fc-image-div" >
            <svg class="w-8 h-8 mb-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
                <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 13h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-.025A5.56 5.56 0 0 0 16 6.5 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 5.207 5.021C5.137 5.017 5.071 5 5 5a4 4 0 0 0 0 8h2.167M10 15V6m0 0L8 8m2-2 2 2"/>
            </svg>
            <p class="fc-image-first-paragrapgh" *ngIf="!selectedFile">
                <span class="text-span">Click here to upload</span> or drag and drop 
            </p>
            <p class="fc-image-second-paragrapgh" *ngIf="!selectedFile">SVG, PNG, JPG or GIF (MAX. 800x400px)</p>
            <p class="fc-image-third-paragrapgh" *ngIf="selectedFile">{{selectedFile.name}}</p>
        </div>
        <input id="dropzone-file" type="file" class="hidden" #imageUpload (change)="uploadImagetoStorage($event)"  />
    </label>
</div>

This is the intended UI:

This is after uploading on the first section:

This is after uploading on the second section:

How do I work on the component to make sure each component serves its own purpose and displays its own image uploaded into it?
